# What is the equivalent of 'match' in the new react version

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

```
function ProductScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails

  const { id } = useParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProductDetails((id)))

  }, [dispatch, match])
```

In this code in the end I used to pass `match` in `useEffect` in the end.
I know I can't do this anymore in the new version so what is the equivalent to `match` now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "match" you mean the `match` object that was a RRDv5 [route prop](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) used to access the route path params, i.e. `props.match.params.id` then there is no equivalent in RRDv6. There are no route props in RRDv6. If you need to access the route path params use the [`useParams` hook](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params).

Based on the code snippet you are *already* using the `useParams` hook and have accessed the `id` route path parameter. It appears that `id` is a dependency in the `useEffect` hook since it is referenced inside the callback, so it should be added to the `useEffect` hook's dependency array.

Example:

```
function ProductScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { loading, error, product } = useSelector(state => state.productDetails);

  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProductDetails((id))); // <-- id referenced here
  }, [dispatch, id]); // <-- should list as dependency here

  ...
```

The `useEffect` hook's callback will be called on the initial render, and when values in the dependency array update the hook's callback will be triggered again. For this reason it's sometimes necessary to do a check that the dependency value is valid.

Example:

```
const { id } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  if (id) {
    // only dispatch action if id is truthy
    dispatch(listProductDetails((id)));
  }
}, [dispatch, id]);
```